Panda read_csv, ignore line that contain specific string
I've a dataframe that list datalogger name and there password. The password is generated inside my script if the datalogger have a blank in the password field. And if there is not a generic password, then I put the specific password in this field for this datalogger.
Third case, for some of datalogger, I set a specific string ('NON') in that field to say to my script not to consider this line : the datalogger must be ignore. That give something like this :
datalog, pwd
A001, 
A002, 123
A003, 
A004,
A005, NON
A006, 456
A007,
A008, NON
A009, 789
A010,

So :
Dataloggers 1, 3, 4, 7, 10 have a generic password.
Dataloggers 2, 6, 9 have a specific password.
Dataloggers 5, 8 must be ignored.
How can I make a pd.read_csv that ignore lines contains 'NON' in the second column ?

I don't think that pandas allows you to skip the rows based on value. You probably have to read the whole data and then apply a filter on it to get the expected outcome.

pd.read_csv doesn't offer such functionality. You can skip rows based on the index, but not on the values. You need to read the whole file, and then filter out the rows you don't need afterwards. E.g., in this case something like: pd.read_csv('file.csv', skipinitialspace=True).query('pwd != "NON"').

Pandas read_csv API does not allow you to skip rows based on values.
Upon investigation I found this Feature Request: "Skiprows" by a condition or set of conditions which suggest an interesting approach(by David Krych).
gen = pd.read_csv('your.csv', chunksize=10000000)
df = pd.concat((x.query('pwd != "NON"') for x in gen), ignore_index=True)

This will read the data in batches and apply a filter to it before the concat operation. Thereby, you can still relay on the C parser and do not have to go through the rows twice.

Hey, sorry for the delay, I've an error using this code : "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'"

Nevermind, I forgot the chunksize parameter in the first step, that's work perfectly : thanks.
